# Post parameter is null

Tags: post, parameters, null

I Have controller with following methods:

```
  public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Tests test)
        {
            test.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            test.Author = User.Identity.Name;
            TestEntities db = new TestEntities();
            db.AddToTests(test);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("CreateQuestion", new { OrderNumber = 1, idTest = test.id });
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult CreateQuestion(int OrderNumber,int idTest)
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateQuestion(Questions question)
        {
            TestEntities db = new TestEntities();
            db.AddToQuestions(question);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("CreateQuestion", new {id = question.id, t = question.Type});
        }
```

The problem is Create methods works right. It get parameter and adds it to DB. But similar method CreateQuestion displays message about question is null.
What do I wrong?

CreateQuestion view

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<test.su.Models.Questions>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Создать вопрос
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Создать вопрос</h2>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("CreateQuestion","Test")) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Вопрос</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type,"Тип вопроса") %>
        </div>

        <% // List of question types
            List<SelectListItem> QuestionTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
            SelectListItem t = new SelectListItem();
            t.Text = "Вопрос с вариантами ответа (флажки или радиокнопки)";
            t.Value = "0";
            QuestionTypes.Add(t);
            t = new SelectListItem();
            t.Text = "Вопрос со свободным ответом (текстовое поле)";
            t.Value = "1";
            QuestionTypes.Add(t);
             %>


        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, QuestionTypes) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type) %>
        </div>

<%--        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderNumber,"Порядковый номер вопроса") %>
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderNumber) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderNumber) %>
        </div>--%>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question,"Текст вопроса") %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Question,2,47,"") %> 
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question) %>
        </div>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.idTest) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idTest) %>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderNumber ) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor( model => model.OrderNumber) %>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Далее" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: can you post the createquestion view.

Comment: And it is complaining that Model.Question is null? Correct?

Comment: Yes. Erorr message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entity

Comment: Hmm, that sounds different actually. Post your model for Questions please.

Comment: what exactly? It have size about 300 line of code and was generated automaticaly with creation ADO.NET Entity Model

Comment: What you need to look for, are columns that MVC will not automatically generate for you. Int columns are a big culprit. You're getting a page error, not a validation error right? A validation error would be red error text on your form. Im' guessing you are getting a page error.

Comment: I'm getting a page error. And I cheked with debugger. At the time of CreateQuestion(Question question) method implementation "question" is realy null.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to figure out without knowing the model. Someone else may provide a better answer, but here is the only thing I can think of for now:

If your Questions model looks like this:

```
public class Questions
{
  int Id {get;set;}
  string Name {get;set;}
  string Description {get;set;}
}
```

What you can do, for now, is alter your controller to accept the individual parameters and create the object yourself. This might help you figure out which critical property in your Model is missing.

```
public ActionResult CreateQuestion(string Name, string Description)
{
  //make the entity yourself
  Questions newQuestion = new Questions()
  {
    Name = Name,
    Description = Description
  }
  //your other code here
}
```

Now normally MVC is smart enough to bind your individual values in your form (view) to your model, but some critical value is missing and causing you issue. Once you've figured out what that is, you can actually restore your controller back to accepting only a Questions object.

Sorry I couldn't help you more.

Good Luck.